# Why is View addOnGlobalLayoutListener not calling when I migrate to Kotlin extensions?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, ongloballayoutlistener

I am trying to migrate my Java class function to Kotlin extension function. The function calls addOnGlobalLayoutListener which registers a callback to be invoked when the global layout state or the visibility of views within the view tree changes. This is my Java function working normally as UtilClass.viewTreeObserverCheck(target) {}

```
public static final void viewTreeObserverCheck(View target, CustomVoidClosure function) {
        if (target.getViewTreeObserver().isAlive()) {
            // callback to be invoked when the global layout state or the visibility of views within the view tree changes
            target.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    target.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    function.invoke();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

I have migrated to Kotlin View extension below. This does not call as view.treeObserverCheck {}

```
fun View.treeObserverCheck(closure: () -> Unit) {
    if (this.viewTreeObserver.isAlive) {
        // callback to be invoked when the global layout state or the visibility of views within the view tree changes
        this.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
            object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
                override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                    viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                    closure.invoke()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fun View.treeObserverCheck(closure: () -> Unit) {
    if (this.viewTreeObserver.isAlive) {
        this.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener (
            object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
                override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                    viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                    closure.invoke()
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

you have used flower brackets instead of round brackets [line no 3]

[image]

Comment: Type Mismatch in the removeOnGlobalLayoutListener because it refers to the View as in Kotlin, referencing a lambda from inside it is not supported.

Comment: i guess u used my second code snippet try 1st one i have also added screen take look at that

Comment: You literally edited and re wrote my code, I don't get it

Comment: Observe Line no 3, in your code u created two global layout listener object one is using SAM constructer ({}) and one is using anonymous class implementation (objet:OnGlo..L..Listner) the second one is just getting created and destroyed and u are calling closure in side that but u haven't set it to tree observer

Comment: Observer your code line no 3 and my snippet line no3 replace' {' this with ' )'